# How to use windows path in os.utime?

Tags: python, windows, filesystems, filepath

I want to change the modification date of the file, so I use `os.utime`, but it can't find a file and I get an error **Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError Can't find file: 'C:\\My folder\\2207222.xlsm'**.

As I understand, the problem is backslashes. So I tried:

1) To replace backslash with empty str, with slash, like `fileLocation.replace("\ ", "")`

2) Also `PureWindowsPath(fileLocation)` doesn't work. When I print *fileLocation* with `print()` it prints "C:/My Folder/2207222.xlsm", but when it fails when it tries to find the file.

3) To use slash instead of backslashes with raw string, like r"C:\My Folder\2207222.xlsm". Output is **Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError Can't find file: 'C:\My Folder\2207222.xlsm'**

4) To use slash instead of backslashes. Output is **Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError Can't find file: "C:\\My Folder\x907222.xlsm"**

Could somebody say how to handle this problem?

Below is one of the examples of code

```
import os
import time
import datetime

fileLocation = 'C:/2207222.xlsm'
year = 2017
month = 11
day = 5
hour = 19
minute = 50
second = 0

date = datetime.datetime(year=year, month=month, day=day, hour=hour, minute=minute, second=second)
modTime = time.mktime(date.timetuple())

print(fileLocation)
os.utime(fileLocation, (modTime, modTime))
```

Comment: `"C:/My Folder/2207222.xlsm"` with forward slashes will work fine, presuming this is exactly the path you're trying to access and haven't changed it for this question. Check the directory for "2207222.xlsm". It may be slightly different than you expect, such as a space before the extension, or use Unicode characters with glyphs that resemble ASCII digits.

Comment: @ErykSun I really have changed names. As you said, it works for this path, it stops working when the name of the file is changed to "2227v222.xlsm"

Answer (score 0):

This can be a really trick problem so I would recommend using `os.path.join`.
For your case I would do it like this:

```py
fileLocation = os.path.join('C:\\', 'My Folder', '2207222.xlsm')
```